# Visual Studio Code python wrong version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to run python. I'm looking at the python version it says: 2.7.16, which I understand is really old.

[image]

Now I click on the gear icon > command palette > select interpreter, and click on the one with the star.

[image]

But when I run the code again, it always defaults back to the version 2.7.16. How do I get VS Code to recognize the right version of python? What I'm finding online about clicking the right python interpreter isn't working, like the answer has to be something different or more involved than just clicking something in the drop-down menu.

Comment: What if you say `!python3 --version`?  When a system has both Python 2 and Python 3, the word `python` usually brings up Python 2.

Comment: oh wow interesting it says 3.11.5

Comment: I believe `!python` is executed as a separate shell command, in which case it wouldn't care what interpreter you have selected inside VS Code.  That command _isn't running inside VS Code_.

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.version)` will show you the current interpreter's version, `!python --version` might not.

Comment: there are 3 python interpreters used: the one used in the shell, the one used by Jupyther, and the one used by VSC when it starts/debugs python scripts, maybe the Jupyther interpreter is the same as the VSC if you start Jupyther after selecting the Python Interpreter in VSC, not likely that a running Jupyther switches interpreter when you select a different Python interpreter in VSC

Comment: How would you change the python version used in the shell?

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first picture indicates that you are using jupyter, for which you should click on the kernel version displayed in the upper right corner to switch the python environment.

[image]

The second picture shows the selected interpreter for the python script, that is, the **`.py`** file.